# OutofMemory while resizing svg file Using Apache Batik

Tags: java, svg, java-2d, batik

i have generated svg file, using following code,

```
public class TestSVGGen {

        static BufferedImage img;

        public void paint(SVGGraphics2D g2d) {
                g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100));
                g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth() ,img.getHeight(), null);
                g2d.setSVGCanvasSize(new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

                img = ImageIO.read(TestSVGGen.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/test_offscreen.jpg"));

                // Get a DOMImplementation.
                DOMImplementation domImpl = GenericDOMImplementation
                                .getDOMImplementation();

                // Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document.
                String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                Document document = domImpl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);

                // Create an instance of the SVG Generator.
                SVGGraphics2D svgGenerator = new SVGGraphics2D(document);


                // Ask the test to render into the SVG Graphics2D implementation.
                TestSVGGen test = new TestSVGGen();
                test.paint(svgGenerator);

                // Finally, stream out SVG to the standard output using
                // UTF-8 encoding.
                boolean useCSS = true; // we want to use CSS style attributes
                File file = new File("image.svg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
                svgGenerator.stream(out, useCSS);


        }
```

now , i want to re size this image canvas to 18,000 * 18000 in dimensions because i want to re size included image to this size , but whenever i try the following code (only portion of the code)

```
svgCanvas.setSize(new Dimension(18000, 18000));
```

the program throws out of memory exception,

what should i do to re size to specified large size , is there any work around like tiling or segmentation of image .

i am very new to batik so please help me

Comment: I think that a resize operation of this size is consuming a lot of memory in the JVM. Increase the memory of the JVM and try again, I have no idea how much it will need or if there's a way around this in the framework itself though....

Comment: @Thihara my question is not about increasing memory , there should a way of segmentation or tiling etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem using **TiledImageTranscoderfrom from contrib directory of batik** and get a successful result without any out of memory error .

the above class uses just 35 MB of memory at a time when running from ECLIPSE IDE and takes 30 Sec on my machine to completely write the image file to disk.

the result is in the TIFF though.